# Function to reverse text characters

Tags: python

I am trying to make a reverse function which takes an input (text) and outputs the reversed version. So `"Polar"` would print `raloP`.

```
def reverse(text):
    list = []
    text = str(text)
    x = len(text) - 1
    list.append("T" * x)
    for i in text:
        list.insert(x, i)
        x -= 1
    print "".join(list)

reverse("Something")
```

Comment: If you just need the functionality, consider the `reversed()` Python builtin.

Comment: There's a lot of misunderstanding in this code. The bit I'm most confused by is `list.append("T" * x)`. What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Slice your string, taking every character, and then set -1 as the step : `"Polar"[::-1]` gives what you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have mentioned, Python already provides a couple of ways to reverse a string. The simple way is to use extended slicing: `s[::-1]` creates a reversed version of string `s`. Another way is to use the `reversed` function: `''.join(reversed(s))`. But I guess it can be instructive to try implementing it for yourself.

There are several problems with your code.

Firstly,

```
list = []
```

You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type. It won't hurt here, but it makes the code confusing, and if you did try to use `list()` later on in the function it would raise an exception with a cryptic error message.

```
text = str(text)
```

is redundant. `text` is already a string. `str(text)` returns the original string object, so it doesn't hurt anything, but it's still pointless.

```
x = len(text) - 1
list.append("T" * x)
```

You have an off-by-one error here. You really want to fill the list with as many items as are in the original string, this is short by one. Also, this code appends the string as a single item to the list, not as `x` separate items of one char each.

```
list.insert(x, i)
```

The `.insert` method inserts new items into a list, the subsequent items after the insertion point get moved up to make room. We don't want that, we just want to overwrite the current item at the `x` position, and we can do that by indexing.

When your code doesn't behave the way you expect it to, it's a Good Idea to add `print` statements at strategic places to make sure that variables have the value that they're supposed to have. That makes it much easier to find where things are going wrong.

---

Anyway, here's a repaired version of your code.

```
def reverse(text):
    lst = []
    x = len(text)
    lst.extend("T" * x)
    for i in text:
        x -= 1
        lst[x] = i
    print "".join(lst)

reverse("Something")
```

**output**

```
gnihtemoS
```

---

Here's an alternative approach, showing how to do it with `.insert`:

```
def reverse(text):
    lst = []
    for i in text:
        lst.insert(0, i)
    print "".join(lst)
```

---

Finally, instead of using a list we could use string concatenation. However, this approach is less efficient, especially with huge strings, but in modern versions of Python it's not as inefficient as it once was, as the `str` type has been optimised to handle this fairly common operation.

```
def reverse(text):
    s = ''
    for i in text:
        s = i + s
    print s
```

---

BTW, you really should be learning Python 3, Python 2 reaches its official End Of Life in 2020.

Comment: This is the only answer the addresses the question (even if the question is only implied)

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks. It's all very well to say "Don't do it like that" and to show the OP better ways to do it, but it's also a bit frustrating when you want to understand why your algorithm doesn't behave the way you expect it to.

Comment: Exactly. You can see my comment on the top post trying to elicit detail like you have in your answer. I'm on a phone so I couldn't post it myself. "Teach a man to fish", and all that :)

Comment: @roganjosh Indeed, which is why I upvoted your comments.

Comment: @EricLues This answer explains in detail why your solution was wrong and how to fix it, you should read every single word of it

Answer (score 4):

You can try :

```
def reverse(text):
  return text[::-1]

print(reverse("Something")) # python 3
print reverse("Something") # python 2
```

Comment: Wow so simple, didn't know that that possible, thanks for info.

Comment: In this case, for the sake of OP, are you able to add some indication of why their code doesn't work? This does the job but it's radically different than their approach that has some serious misunderstanding behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Easier way to do so:

```
def reverse(text):
  rev = ""
  i = len(text) - 1
  while i > -1:
    rev += text[i]
    i = i - 1
  return rev


print(reverse("Something"))
```

result: `gnihtemoS`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
    print "something"[::-1]
```

Comment: While this is the shortest method, the question asks for a function

Comment: Oh,okay my mistake